# How import all images from xml in python with a bad structure

Tags: python, xml, magento2

I'm new to Python and have trouble importing photos from an xml file. Unfortunately I understand that the xml file is crooked and poorly created. But unfortunately in this format it will come to the server and it is not possible to change it.

XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>
    <test-item>
            <sku>098730</sku>
            <name><![CDATA[Bala bla bla]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[Bala bla bla. Bala bla bla. Bala bla bla.]]>
            </description>
            <image><![CDATA[image url]]></image>
            <image2><![CDATA[image url]]></image2>
            <image3><![CDATA[image url]]></image3>
            <image4><![CDATA[image url]]></image4>
    </test-item>
</test>
```

How can I properly import images (`<image>`, `<image2>`,... etc) from this file which have a bad structure?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you mean by "import"?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the XML, it's valid. CDATA sections are used to hold text that may contained reserved characters and would throw errors, e.g. `http://example.com?a=1&b=2`

Comment: @mzjn, i mean importing images to magento, but that's it. The problem is that all products in the xml file have a different number of photos, .... some have 30-60 photos (<image>, .... <image61> for example). I can't read and separate photos for each sku product. All image urls are valid and do not contain reserved characters. If the image structure were as follows:

<images>
    <image> </image>
    <image2> </image2>
    <image3> </image3>
....
</images>, I think there would be no problems.

Comment: What does magento have to do with this? If you want to extract the image URLs from the XML file, just say so.

Comment: @mzjn, yes, i try to get all url images according to each sku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>
    <test-item>
            <sku>098730</sku>
            <name><![CDATA[Bala bla bla]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[Bala bla bla. Bala bla bla. Bala bla bla.]]>
            </description>
            <image><![CDATA[image url1]]></image>
            <image2><![CDATA[image url2]]></image2>
            <image3><![CDATA[image url43]]></image3>
            <image4><![CDATA[image url4]]></image4>
    </test-item>
</test>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
images = []
counter = 0
while True:
  if counter == 0:
    img = root.find('.//image')
    if img is None:
      break
    images.append(img.text)
    counter =+ 2
  else:
      img = root.find('.//image{}'.format(counter))
      if img is None:
        break
      images.append(img.text)
      counter += 1
for idx,image in enumerate(images,1):
  print('{}) {}'.format(idx,image))
```

output

```
1) image url1
2) image url2
3) image url43
4) image url4
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. Using your code, but have an error :  img = root.find(f'.//image')
                                                                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @WacekT What is the python version that you are using? Make sure you use python version >= 3.6

Comment: Using ver python 3.5 (

Comment: Any option to upgrade to 3.6 ?

Comment: I will try to do it.

Comment: @WacekT no need to do that - please retry - it should work with python 3.5 as well

Comment: I see in to terminal: python -V
Python 2.7.13.  But on server, I run command :  /usr/bin/python3.5 imp_images.py. and I'm already confused. maybe I still need to update the python version on the server?

Comment: Take the current code and try to run it. share the result. **Note** that the code was modified, so copy & paste it again

Comment: thanks for your help! Code working! Output:  1.0 Start
1) image url1
2) image url2
3) image url43
4) image url4
 1.2 Stop

Comment: @WacekT Good news. Glad I managed to help. Please accept my answer.